# Trying to return a target name from a mouse event in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript

I'm new to AS3 and am trying to get the target name from a mouse click by using a simple getValue function but I am getting the error 1067: Implicit coercion of a value of type void to an unrelated type String.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
var _userInput:String = new String();
_userInput = btn_0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getValue);

function getValue(e:MouseEvent):String{
   return e.target.name;
}
```

This may be a simple error I'm making but I'm not seeing what it is.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you think about it, the return would go to the event dispatcher, not the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't actually do it that way, as addEventListener returns *void* not the type the listener function returns (String).

```
[Bindable] var targetName:String;

var _userInput:String = new String();
_userInput = targetName;
btn_0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getValue);

function getValue(e:MouseEvent):void{
targetName = e.target.name;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
btn_0.mouseChildren=false
btn_0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getValue);

function getValue(e:MouseEvent):void{
    trace(e.target.name);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of explanation to go with this code-change so others can understand how to fix similar problems in the future.

Comment: Just as the original question. Add btn_0.mouseChildren=false to disable clicking on the children of the target. This gives you e.target exactly the btn_0 and not other element inside the btn_0. So using e.target.name works. Read more here http://www.thoughtprocessinteractive.com/blog/the-power-and-genius-of-mousechildren-and-mouseenabled

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have given your button an instance name of btn_0

```
var _userInput:String;

btn_0.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, getValue);

function getValue(e:MouseEvent):void{
_userInput = e.target.name;
trace(_userInput);
}
```

Comment: So the only signature that can come of a MouseEvent event listener is void?  I cannot set the function to return any value?

Comment: You have to understand how the events work in actionscript. Even if the getValue function was to return something, you would not be able to get the result unless you called the function yourself (which kills the purpose of events).
In your case, you try to assign into a variable the return value of the function addEventListener, not to your callback function. The addEventListener function does not return a value, hence the error.
Read this for a better understanding of the event system:
[link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/EventDispatcher.html)